# "first type int, second type boolean" java

Tags: java

so I'm just playing around with some stuff I learnt, making some pointless calculator. Before anyone says, I know this could be done much more simply!

I'm getting this error though on my while statement (bad operand types for binary operator '||' first type: int, second type: boolean")

it's also throwing problems with the

```
int AA = A + B;
int AB = A * B;
int AC = A / B;
```

saying cannot find symbol.

```
class cases{ //1-4  sums with cases, delete after//
  public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Welcome to a pointless calculator.");

      int A = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int B = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      switch (A){
        case 1:
          System.out.print("You entered 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.print("You entered 2");
          break;
        case 3: 
          System.out.print("You entered 3");
         break;
        case 4:
          System.out.print("You entered 4");
      }
      while ( A || B > 4){
        System.out.print("please enter numbers 1-4");
        break;


      }
      switch (B) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println(" and 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println(" and 2");
          break;
        case 3: 
          System.out.println(" and 3");
        break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println(" and 4");
      }

      }
      {

        int AA = A + B;
        int AB = A * B;
        int AC = A / B;


        System.out.print("the answers added = ");
        System.out.println(AA);
        System.out.print("the answers multipled = ");
        System.out.println(AB);
        System.out.print("the answers divided = "); 
        System.out.println(AC);



      }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while ( A || B > 4){
```

That expression breaks down like this:

```
while (
    A
    ||
    B > 4
){
```

`A` is of type `int`, but you're treating it like a `boolean`. You can't do that in Java. You may have meant:

```
while ( A > 4 || B > 4){
```

---

There may well be further problems in the code. For instance, you have a block not associated with anything at the end of your code. I *think* in Java that ends up being an instance initializer block, but frankly I think you need to step back and work through some tutorials.

Comment: thank you - the extra problem im having now is that it does prints the out.prints at the end regardless of valid arg entries.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional expression inside a `while` needs to resolve to a `boolean`. The two operands of the `||`  operator need to evaluate to `boolean` values. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

This

```
  while ( A || B > 4){
```

is not syntactically correct.

Also at this point in the code

```
...
  }
  {

    int AA = A + B;
    int AB = A * B;
    int AC = A / B;


    System.out.print("the answers added = ");
    System.out.println(AA);
    System.out.print("the answers multipled = ");
    System.out.println(AB);
    System.out.print("the answers divided = "); 
    System.out.println(AC);



  }
  }
```

You are closing your `main` method block and starting an instance initializer. At this point `A` and `B` are no longer in scope.

If you indent your brackets appropriately, you will see where your blocks end.